# How are stored percentage fields ? They don't always return the same value

Tags: formula, custom-field, trailhead, documentation, percent

I have a field of type Percent(3,2) named Sector__c.VatRate__c.
I initialized it with anonymous apex withe values like 5.5, 10, 20, etc. The code looks like that :

```
sec.VatRate__c = 10;
update sec;
```

Now I have a formula field on Opportunity named AmountWithTax__c, the formula is :

```
AmountWithoutTax__c * ( 1 + VatRate__c /100 )
```

I expected, for a record having `AmountWithoutTax__c` set to 200, a result of 220, but I get 200.2.

Changing the formula to

```
AmountWithoutTax__c * ( 1 + VatRate__c )
```

gives me the expected result.

[Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/advanced_formulas/numbers_formulas) states this :

> A Percent is stored as a number divided by 100, meaning that 100% is represented as 1, 90% as 0.9, and so on.

So everything so far is ok.

But if I query the Sector object, the value returned for VatRate__c is 10, not 0.1. Worse, if I execute this code :

```
Sector__c[] sec = [Select VatRate__c from Sector__c where VatRate__c = 10];
Double d = 200.00;
System.debug(sec[0].VatRate__c);
System.debug(d * (1 + sec[0].VatRate__c) );
```

I get `10.00` and `2200`.

That looks not consistent to me, I expect an Apex code to return the same value as a matching formula...

Also the trailhead statement looks inaccurate, the percentage value seems to be stored as 90 for 90%, not as 0.9.

I tried to re-set the percentage value from the interface rather than from apex, but that changed nothing.

So am I missing something or is the trailhead doc wrong. And why does the formula return a number divided by 100 while Apex doesn't ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Formulas behave like Excel formulas, and if you format a cell as a Percent, Excel automatically handles conversion of percentages so your formulas "just work." Give it a try sometime in Excel (or Open Office Calc, or Google Spreadsheets, etc):

```
     A    B    C
1    200  10%  =A1*B1
```

In fact, do this in any reasonable spreadsheet program, and this should work. The reason why formulas work that way is to provide a consistent experience with inexperienced administrators who may have used a spreadsheet before.

Originally, the SOAP API was the only real API available, with others not available until years later (including Apex). In the SOAP API, a percent is expressed as written on a screen. I'm not entirely sure why, but it may have to do with the fact that there is no `xsd:percent` data type in the WSDL language. Later, the Apex language was invented and used the same query engine as the SOAP version, and yet later, REST was added, so it had to be consistent with the previous APIs.

The difference appears to be grounded in how the product was meant to be used, and  technical restraints for the API options available from the earliest days of the API. All you really need to remember is that Formulas and APIs are different because of different product requirements for each, and that formulas automatically do the "divide by 100" for you.

Comment: Thank you sfdcfox, that's interesting ! I still think that it should be correctly documented. The statement in trailhead is wrong, the value is not `stored as as a number divided by 100` but stored as a number and divided by 100 in formulas. I didn't test in flows, I wonder what happens if you set a decision condition as PercentField__c < 50. Will that be true for 60% (0.6 < 50) or false (60 > 50) ? I don't need the answer, just showing that you can't predict the behaviour until you test it...

Comment: @EmmanuelBRUNO It's consistent. If it's a formula, it expresses in the decimal form, including Workflow, Processes, Flows, etc. If it's not a formula, it expresses in the percent form. I do agree that the documentation should be clearer, and trailheads are not even written by the people who write the documentation, so there's a bit of disconnect. For now, I'd log documentation bugs for the unclear parts in the documentation, and contact the trailhead team to see if they can write more concise language. This is all fixable, someone just needs to step up.

Comment: Well I'll try to find time for that, but I'm not familiar with the process.

Comment: So the same value, let's say 5% will return `5` in Apex, and `0.05` in formulas. Do you want to know the funny part ? Make a formula field of type percentage that references this custom field, it will return 500, and display 500% in the UI !!!

Comment: @EmmanuelBRUNO That's a mathematical expectation. If you apply the same operation multiple times, you get this effect.

Comment: No : it's stored as 5. You said `formulas automatically do the "divide by 100" `, so my reference in the formula should divide it by 100 => 0.05. And then the UI could display 5 since it's a percentage type, but never 500. I would have understood 0.05% displayed because of this division but not 500. And even though the same data returned with 3 different values no matter the explanation, is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please, refer to this article:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000351429&type=1
Even though it is a bit counterintuitive, it looks understandable.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged, and may be deleted. *(See: [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers))* Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/374805/edit) you answer to add more information. *(From [How do I write a good answer?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer): "...please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link....")*

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty annoying and confusing. Either way, manually changing the API version to 53 (from 54) in my case made Flow evaluate 90% as 0.9 instead of 90 which is what I was looking for/expecting.

I know this isn't a great solution, but got the job done for now.

More details here: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000351429&type=1